# Poweshell: force save of xlsm

Tags: powershell, save, xlsm

First time here, hope the Community can help :-)

I tried the following with Powershell

- it works well with an xlsx file
- but it is KO with xlsm

EDIT:

I changed the code sequence below and force .DisplayAlert .
CSV files save are OK, but with console error.

Any idea for these errors ?

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynm2o.jpg)

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$wb = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($fullpathExcelFile)

Start-Sleep -s 30

foreach ($ws in $wb.Worksheets) {
          
            $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
            $ws.SaveAs("$fullpathOutputdir\" + $ws.Name + ".csv", 6)
            Write-Host "Save csv $ws.Name"
}

$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

$wb.Save()

$Excel.Quit()
```

Thanks !

Comment: Question: If you are not modifying the contents of the workbook, then why re-save it immediately after opening it?  If this is a minimal example, then ensure your full code does not modify the `.DisplayAlerts` property, or accidentally reuse the `$Excel` variable -- which might reset `.DisplayAlerts` back to `$true` (default).

Comment: Hi @leeharvey1 you are right: before I made a refreshall before Save, which I now manage in VBA directly in xls. I changed code to force .DisplayAlert to $false . Anyway I face now error, but no more the save pop-up. I will edit post. Thanks.